# Pycharm using two projects to run

Tags: python, pycharm

So I am trying to submit some coursework for university, but when I compress the project and send it to my friend, he cannot run it.

I noticed at the top of the console there is this line

```
"/Users/maxculley/Desktop/PART 2/bin/python" "/Users/maxculley/Desktop/UNI WORK/YEAR 3/Data structures and algorithms/Coursework 1/PART 2/CODE/main.py"
```

I located the files on my desktop and it seems as though I can only run this if the project has these files at that file path.

Anyone know why the project is using these files from two project?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED -- Realised I didn't need to compress the whole folder, just the python files, the interpreter is what was causing the issue as this is what was located on my home screen